# Roof warranty 5 year versus 25 year- Would it allow me to get more money back in a house I plan to sell?

Tags: real-estate, housing, house-sale

I inherited a 1960 house worth over 200k in tax assessment. It's has some issues though....foundation and internal renovation to become updated in styles.

I bought full coverage insurance for it. A month later, the insurance said I had to replace the roof or they would drop the insurance.

I got 2 bids from contractors and one bid from a company.

The lowest bid was from a roofing contractor(reputable from a friend who they did their house) for 9k - with a 5 year warranty.

The highest bid was from the company for 14k with a 25 year warranty. The company has been in business for 5 years with 5 good ratings on yelp.

Both warranties are transferable.

I plan to sell the house in a year with the probate is over. Probably as is without renovations. Would I be able to sell the house at a higher price and make my money back with the 25 year warranty versus the 5 year warranty? Would the warranty make that much of a difference in the selling price?

Comment: Are they using comparable materials? Do the warranties both cover workmanship and materials?

Comment: The issue with a 25 year warranty is that if the company goes bankrupt the next year the warranty could be practically void (if nobody buys the bankrupt company). The same would happen with the 5 year warranty, of course, but then you get it cheaper.

Comment: Is the new buyer likely to rip the roof off the house.as part of a renovation? If they are the extra warranty provides nothing to them.

Comment: "The issue with a 25 year warranty is that if the company goes bankrupt the next year the warranty could be practically void". This happened to me in the UK after 5 years of a 25 year warranty. Those things are just fancy certificates that are worth nothing. In England and Wales an intending house buyer has to do a survey to qualify for a mortgage on a property, which includes roof condition. The buyer & lender want the work done, not a certificate.

Comment: You may also want to check how much warranty you get on a roof by law.

Comment: "I plan to sell the house in a year with the probate is over" what role do you play in the estate? Do you have access to the property before probate is over?

Comment: Be sure you understand what "25 year warranty" means.  It is often the rating of the shingles themselves offered by the manufacturer.  If the roof needs reshingling in 20 years, they'll pay 20% of the cost of the new shingles, but not labour.  Often it isn't worth the trouble of applying for.  The *real* meaning of the 25 is in the weight of the shingles.  "25 year" shingles are more likely to endure the sun for a longer time and not to blow off as easily as "5 year" shingles would.  Given how much of the cost is for labour, paying for the better quality shingles is usually a good idea.

Comment: @RayButterworth That's what prompted my initial question, I've never heard of a 5-year shingle, so I suspected that might be a 5-year workmanship warranty. Typically you have choices of material with a given company, there's no way in this case that the $5k difference can be accounted for by shingle quality.

Comment: I don't think it can be stressed enough that you really need to compare the details of the two quotes. The warranty should be the least of your concerns. What materials are being used (what quality shingles?) Are the quotes intended to be all-inclusive? What about removal of old materials? What about costs for hidden damage? Are both contractors insured? Forget about the warranties. They're an afterthought at best, IME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A person buying a house has so many important issues to address.  One question that comes up a lot is the age of the roof, and replacing an old roof can make it easier to sell your house.

Given the many things a buyer has to address, however, I expect that it would extremely rare for a buyer to even ask about the length of warranty of the roof.  Even if they did, it seems like it would not be a major factor in the purchase decision for the reasons noted in the comments.

Comment: I am not sure. THis is GENERALLY correct, but given the current state of the house being basically a ruin (issues in foundation can be super critical) it likely means a total and full renovation. The new roof may hinder any change on the outside for a house like that. 2000 worth in tax assessment is basically worthless.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typeo. I meant 200k in tax assessment.

Answer (score 1):

> The lowest bid was from a roofing contractor(reputable from a friend
>   who they did their house) for 9k - with a 5 year warranty.
>
> The highest bid was from the company for 14k with a 25 year warranty.
>   The company has been in business for 5 years with 5 good ratings on
>   yelp.

5 ratings on yelp in 5 years isn't a lot of ratings.

Besides the warranty a big issue is what happens to the guaranteed price if they find rot when they pull up the old roof. The replacement of the plywood, and maybe even a joist or two can make the cost rise significantly. Some include an expected amount of replacement into their bid, others make you pay for everything. Each section of plywood can cost $50-$100 more depending on material. Facing this issue after they have removed the old roof doesn't give you much leverage when negotiating the rate.

If the person buying the home will live in the home, the idea that they don't have to replace the roof for 10+ years makes the longer warranty a good thing. But if you expect that they will be removing some or all of the roof as part of a full renovation project then the longer warranty might not mean much to them.